# Arch Linux RPI: How accurate is the time on the RPi in Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, ntp

Currently I'm working on an application on my RPi which will be monitoring a set of GPIOs in real-time where the exact time when the GPIO turns HIGH is crucial for my application.

How the time is being dealt with on the RPi with the Arch Linux OS; is it synchronized towards a UDP NTP Time Server? If that's the case, is it being updated continuously in a background thread/daemon like other Linux installations? Or is it perhaps updated each time a call to get the time is made?

Because two events might occur on two (or more) GPIOs simultaneously I need to implement the fastest solution possible to get the real-time functionality.

The actual date is not important when the specific event happens; instead, the exact time relative to the other events is. The data recorded will be shown in a graph where the spacing between the events should be as exact as possible.

How is time handled on the RPi with Arch Linux, and how accurate is it in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: You can choose between using `ntp` or `systemd-timesyncd` (I would recommend [the latter](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd) in conjuction with `systemd-networkd`).

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry, but I'm rather new to Linux and I don't really understand what `systemd-timesyncd` and `systemd-networkd`, An explanation would be greatly appreciated! Thank you. Nevermind, I missed your hyperlink to the systemd-timesyncd explanation. :S

Comment: No problem: [this might also be helpful](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2014/06/28/vpn/) for context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with most things in Arch, there isn't a default time management tool set up; you can choose between several [time synchronisation options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time#Time_synchronization).

Give the RaspberryPi's lack of a [RTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock), I would suggest that you ensure that you use a tool that can store the last time to disk and then references that at boot time to pull the clock out of the [dawn of UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Using a combination of [systemd-timesyncd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd), with an optional configuration file for your preferred time servers in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`, and [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd) will bring your network up swiftly at boot and correct any drift in your clock *as early as practicably possible*. The daemon will then sync your clock at periodic intervals (around every 30 minutes).