# NTPd Not Syncing on RaspberryPi

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, ntp, ntpd

Since my hardware (RasberryPi) does not have a hardware-clock, each bootup warps us back to the 1970's, so I use NTP. The gateway on the network I am on provides an NTP-Server service.

my `/etc/ntp.conf` looks like the follwing (commented lines ommitted)

```
server 192.168.170.254 //gateway that hosts the service
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
```

`/etc/profile`:

```
[connect wifi...]
timeout 15 ntpd -q -g //forces update so I have a time to work with, times out so I don't get a total hang if it doesn't work
systemctl start ntpd.service //in hopes that I will work at some point and to keep it in sync
date //see if it worked
[start main program...]
```

Am I missing something?

**Edit**
Output of `ntpd -q`:

```
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[349]: ntpd 4.2.7p446@1.2483-o Wed Jul  2 03:23:39 UTC 2014 (1): Starting
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[349]: Command line: /usr/bin/ntpd -q
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[349]: proto: precision = 3000 usec (-18)
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[349]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[349]: Listen normally on 1 lo 127.0.0.1:123
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[349]: Listen normally on 2 wlan0 192.168.170.100:123
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[349]: Listening on routing socket on fd #19 for interface updates
#hangs here till interrupted
```

Output of `systemctl status ntpd`:

```
* ntpd.service - Network Time Service
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ntpd.service; disabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 1969-12-31 17:00:43 MST, 16s ago
Process: 332 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ntpd -g -u ntp:ntp -p /run/ntpd.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 335 (ntpd)
CGroup: /system.slice/ntpd.service
        `-335 /usr/bin/ntpd -g -u ntp:ntp -p /run/ntpd.pid

DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[332]: ntpd 4.2.7p446@1.2483-o Wed Jul  2 03:23:39 UTC 2014 (1): Starting
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[332]: Command line: /usr/bin/ntpd -g -u ntp:ntp -q /run/ntpd.pid
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi systemd[1]: PID file /run/ntpd.pid not readable (yet?) after start.
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[335]: proto: precision = 3000 usec (-18)
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[335]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[335]: Listen normally on 1 lo 127.0.0.1:123
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[335]: Listen normally on 2 wlan0 192.168.170.100:123
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi ntpd[335]: Listening on routing socket on fd #19 for interface updates
DEC 31 17:00:43 alarmpi systemd[1]: Started Network Time Service
```

Comment: Where is the actual problem? In the direct call to ntpd, In the ntpd that was started as a service or do you just know that the output of `date` is wrong? What is the output of the call to ntpd and of `systemctl status ntpd` and `ntpq -p`?

Comment: @Wieland I can't tell. All I know is that neither works, since time doesn't get updated

Comment: @Mark: Please attach the output of `systemctl status ntpd` and `ntpq -p`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder done.

Comment: According to the `systemctl` output, the Pi's clock is being updated. If the time isn't correct, I'd suspect it is the router: try using an NTP pool server directly (or switch to `systemd-timesyncd`)...

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146451/arch-linux-rpi-how-accurate-is-the-time-on-the-rpi-in-linux/

Comment: @jasonwryan would you know a way to manually probe the server I'm using? something like a `timeping` that responds to stdout?

Comment: also @Wieland outputs added

Comment: No: I would sync to a pool server and see if that is more accurate. As I said in my other answer, `systemd-{networkd,timesyncd}` is a better option for the Pi.

Comment: @jasonwryan I'm using a local server, because the WiFi is not routed to the internet. I'll triple-check with the responsible admin, wether he is 1000% sure the service works as intended

Answer (score 1):

@asonwryan's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146454/78871) to  another question provides a good solution to this problem. Hardware problems (lack of Real Time Clock) make this a bit difficult.

> Give the RaspberryPi's lack of a [RTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock), I would suggest that you ensure that you use a tool that can store the last time to disk and then references that at boot time to pull the clock out of the [dawn of UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).
>
> Using a combination of [systemd-timesyncd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd), with an optional configuration file for your preferred time servers in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`, and [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-networkd) will bring your network up swiftly at boot and correct any drift in your clock *as early as practicably possible*. The daemon will then sync your clock at periodic intervals (around every 30 minutes).